# The difference between readr::read_csv() and read_csv()

Tags: r, import

I saw some people use `readr::read_csv()` command instead of `read_csv()`.
What is the difference between `readr::read_csv` and `read_csv`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two reasons why you would want to use the `<package>::<function>` command instead of `<function>`:

1. you don't want to upload the whole package, but you want to have access to a single function
2. the function name of one package is the same as the function name of another package; to distinguish them, declare the package to which it belongs with `<package>::`.

For example both `dplyr` and `stats` contain `filter` function. If you load `dplyr` after `stats` you will have `dplyr::filter()` masks `stats::filter()`, so to distinguish them we use `dplyr::filter()` or `stats::filter()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now, I know why people use <package>::<function>.

Comment: if my answer was useful to you, if you want please consider whether to accept it